How to calculate the FX ON and TN swap points - updated
i updated my questions as below, really confused about calculation the FX ON and TN swap points from SP. Please help in details. Thanks.


This question is similar to: Understanding FX forward points and market usage. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. It's always BBBB (bank buys base at bid).

Pls post your question and details in text rather than as part of a picture. That makes it more convenient for people to read it and, if necessary, reuse parts of it in an answer.
